# Distribution of prime divisors. What is the distribution of the product of the distinct prime divisors?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, probability-theory, prime-numbers

Let $N_n$ be an integer randomly chosen from among the first $n$ integers: 
$P[N_n = m] = 1/n$ for $ 1\le m \le n.$ Let $Q_{ni}$ be the distinct prime divisors of $N_n$, ordered by size: $Q_{n1} > Q_{n2} > \cdots,$ where $Q_{nv}=1$ if $N_n$ has fewer than $v$ distinct prime divisors, and let $T_n = \Pi_v Q_{nv}$ be the product of the distinct prime divisors. In this case, why is 
$$E[\log T_n] = \sum_{p \le n} \frac{1}{n} \Big \lfloor \frac{n}{p}\Big \rfloor \log p?$$

Comment: @hardmath I'm not sure what you mean by the squarefree divisor of $N$. The first index of $Q$ just determines the largest possible integer $N$ takes, then given $N_n = m$, the $Q$'s are $>1$ for the distinct prime divisors of $m$.

Comment: You seem to use $v$ both as a variable  (the index of the product) and as a constant (to which the number of prime divisors of $N$ can be compared).  Possibly it is meant to be a parameter?

Comment: I believe the way you have written it is quite unclear (though perhaps I misunderstand it).  The way I interpret it:  the random variable $T$ is evaluated by choosing a random integer $i$  uniformly from $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ at which point $T_n=\prod_{p\,|\,i}p$.  In any case, I used this definition in my post below.

Comment: Perhaps a numerical example would be illuminating.  If $n=4$ then $i$ can only be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in which case we see that $T_4$ is, respectively, $\{1,2 , 3, 2\}$.  Thus $P(T_4=1)=P(T_4=3)=\frac 14$ and $P(T_4=2)=\frac 12$.

Comment: @lulu Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$E[\log T_n]=\frac 1n\times \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{p\,|\,i}\log p$$

But the double sum can be rewritten as $$\sum_{p≤n}a(n)_p\log p$$

Where $a(n)_p$ is defined to be the number of integers $i\in \{1,\cdots, n\}$ which are divisible by $p$.  It is easy to see that $$a(n)_p=\Big \lfloor \frac np\Big \rfloor$$ and we are done.